# What exactly does mean lock mode conflicts with another lock mode in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking, isolation-level

In Table 13.2. Conflicting Lock Modes [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) we see that ROW EXCLUSIVE conflicts with the SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes, but it **doesn't conflict with itself**.
Consider following example.
I start 2 transactions T1 and T2 simultaneously.

Then in **T1** I execute following commands:

```
my_db=# begin;
BEGIN
my_db=*# update t set color = 'green' where id = 2;
UPDATE 1
```

Then in **T2** I execute following commands:

```
my_db=# begin;
BEGIN
my_db=*# update t set color = 'blue' where id = 2;
```

T2 is become **locked** after that.

Then I select all locks for relation **t**:

```
my_db=# select lock.locktype,lock.mode,lock.transactionid,lock.relation::regclass as relation,lock.virtualxid from pg_locks as lock where locktype = 'relation';
 locktype |       mode       | transactionid |  relation   | virtualxid
----------+------------------+---------------+-------------+------------
 relation | RowExclusiveLock |               | t_color_idx |
 relation | RowExclusiveLock |               | t           |
 relation | RowExclusiveLock |               | t_color_idx |
 relation | RowExclusiveLock |               | t           |
 relation | AccessShareLock  |               | pg_locks    |
(5 rows)

my_db=#
```

I see there are only locks of **RowExclusiveLock** and **AccessShareLock** modes.
But T2 is locked.
But according Table 13.2. Conflicting Lock Modes **RowExclusiveLock** **doesn't conflict with itself**.

Ok, **RowExclusiveLock** conflicts with **ACCESS EXCLUSIVE**.
Consider new example: I start 2 **new** transactions T1 and T2 simultaneously.
In T1:

```
my_db=# begin;
BEGIN
my_db=*#
my_db=*# alter table t alter column color TYPE varchar(400);
ALTER TABLE
my_db=*#
```

In T2:

```
my_db=# begin;
BEGIN
my_db=*# update t set color = 'black' where id = 2;
```

T2 is become **locked** after that like first example.

Then I select all locks for relation **t**:

```
my_db=# select lock.locktype,lock.mode,lock.transactionid,lock.relation::regclass as relation,lock.virtualxid from pg_locks as lock where locktype = 'relation';
 locktype |        mode         | transactionid |  relation   | virtualxid
----------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+------------
 relation | AccessShareLock     |               | pg_locks    |
 relation | RowExclusiveLock    |               | t           |
 relation | AccessShareLock     |               | t_color_idx |
 relation | AccessExclusiveLock |               | t_color_idx |
 relation | AccessExclusiveLock |               | 3028689     |
 relation | ShareLock           |               | t           |
 relation | AccessExclusiveLock |               | t           |
(7 rows)

my_db=#
```

I see there is also **AccessExclusiveLock**.
According Table 13.2. Conflicting Lock Modes **RowExclusiveLock** conflicts with **AccessExclusiveLock**.
**But behaviour in second example is the same in first**: T2 is become **locked**.

So,

1. what does mean "lock mode conflicts with another lock mode" in PostgreSQL?
2. Why **RowExclusiveLock** doesn't conflicts with itsel, but it blocks another transaction?

I expected that conflicts means locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two lock modes conflict, two different transactions cannot take them at the same time on the same object. The first to come takes the lock, and the second one gets blocked until the first one releases the lock (commits).

`SHARE` lock is a lock that prevents all concurrent data modifications on the table and is taken by `CREATE INDEX`. `ROW EXCLUSIVE` is the lock taken by transactions that want to perform `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on a table. It conflicts with the `SHARE` lock for obvious reasons, and it does not conflict with itself because two concurrent transactions are allowed to modify the data in the same table concurrently (as long as they don't try to modify the same rows, which is handled by row locks).

Comment: And  Row-Level Locks are not displayed in pg_locks? Is it possible to figure out is there row level lock acquired for some relation?

Comment: Row locks only stay in the lock table for a short while. The are persisted on the row itself. You can examine tthem with the `pgrowlocks` extension.